# Apply text-overflow: ellipsis into a <li> after two lines

Tags: html, css

I have a list which have dynamic lengths on each list item. The maximum lines of the list would be 2. For those texts which overflow the 2 lines should be ended with dots. can user "white-space: nowrap;". but how can i specify the 2 lines. Any suggestions are highly appreaciated.[example](http://jsfiddle.net/ooo8me34/)

```css
  li {
    line-height: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100px;
    border: 2px solid #ff0000;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>long long name</li>
  <li>long long name long long name</li>
  <li>long long name long long name long long name</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: please can you show your code. if the fidlde gets fixed/isnt avaialbe then the quetion wont help others. also can you please "The maximum lines of the list would be 2", none of the text in your example is on more then one line

Comment: Try this for multi line ellipsis: http://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/qlFdp

Answer (score 0):

Please see [my fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/0p1kz8q3/)

I used pseudo elements to position an ellipsis on the right side of every second line. I also added some fading gradient background since this method will not cut off whole words.

**CSS**

```
li {
    width:100px;
    max-height: 50px;
    line-height: 25px;
    border:2px solid #ff0000;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li:after {
    content:"...";
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, #fff 30%, #fff 100%);;
}
```